# get value of input field with xpath

Tags: php, xpath

I'm trying to get the value of a hidden form with xpath,
there are several input fields

```
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML($html);

        // grab all the page
        $x = new DOMXPath($dom);

        $nodes = $x->query('/html/body/div/div[4]/div[2]/input');

        foreach ($nodes as $node) {

            echo $name1  = $node->getValue;     

        }
```

this is the HTML code:

```
<input type="hidden" value="1199" name="year">
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply put `@value` at the end of your query.

Answer (score 7):

use:

```
/html/body/div/div[4]/div[2]/input[@name='year']/@value
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
/html/body/div/div[4]/div[2]/input[@value=1199 and @name='year']
```